# How to exchange keys despite a MITM, using some short known password?

Tags: key-exchange

The simple scenario is two devices on one WiFi network sitting side by side. The user can copy a short code from one device to the other to be the "password" however this code can't be too long. Let's assume it's at most 12 decimal digits. The devices will only allow one attempt so any MITM attacker will have to take a chance with only 1 in a trillion for success, which will also alert the user that he (the attacker) is there, so that would be secure "enough" for me. This is all there is, that is, there is no server which both devices have its public keys.

But how would this work? I thought of something like the following but ran into a problem. If there's a standard solution for this key-exchange scenario, please feel free to ignore the following:

> I thought device **d1** can create a random number in the above mentioned
> range and use it as the key for Rijndael encryption of its public
> encryption key but without a need for padding so that all ciphertexts
> can be "decrypted" so that the MITM won't be able to brute force which is correct
> by being alerted that a wrong one is wrong. The second device **d2** then uses that password to
> decrypt the ciphertext (which is transmitted over wifi). It then uses it
> to encrypt and send **d1** its (**d2**'s) keys. The idea is that the MITM
> won't know which of the trillion possible deciphered texts is correct.
> And even when he (the MITM) sees the message back from **d2**, won't be
> able to brute force it, because the plaintext of the sent ciphertext
> will be random-like (because it's a public key of an unknown key pair)
> and will be encrypted like the first one, where there is no padding and
> therefore an attacker can't see whether they got the correct plaintext
> or an error.
>
> Unfortunately this might not work because the MITM might be able to
> preemptively craft a set of keys (- a trillion decipherings of some
> key) where the key used can be detected from the ciphertext, and send that key to **d2** and then discover the "password" from **d2**'s response. Can this
> be done?
>
> Also, the usual rule of not rolling out my own encryption scheme.

So, is there a safe way to exchange keys despite a MITM, using some short known password? (Preferably with forward secrecy such that brute forcing, if it takes a month, won't give the attacker the ability to start impersonating one of the devices from then on.)

Comment: Seems like you're describing [PAKEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement).

Comment: PSK, signature, fingerprinting.

Comment: @cisnjxqu Thanks. I followed your link and tried to follow it for details. So far the one I've looked at is a 65k character RFC. Is there some simple algorithm, or are they all complicated?

Comment: @kelalaka Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ispiro: they (PAKE schemes) tend to all get complicated when you account for setup, and the possibility that server data leaks. See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58885/555).

Comment: Also relevant, it would appear that a SAS (short authentication string)-authenticated scheme would suffice for you. That is a scheme where the devices display a code independently and the user only need to check if they match. Note how PAKEs require a stronger functionality because there you'd allow the user to _set_ any such authentication string.

Comment: @fgrieu In my scenario there is no "server". Are you referring to a 3rd device helping out? Because I'm talking about a case where that's not even an option. I'm also not worried about either of the devices being compromised (if that's what you meant). I just need a simple algorithm.

Comment: @SEJPM I'm fine with a device creating the "password" as mentioned in my question. My plan above includes the user copying the password because it seems even more complicated to try having one device communicate it to the other securely. How would that even work?

Comment: @SEJPM Also, you state that: `PAKEs ... allow the user to set any such authentication string.` - Are all PAKEs really like that? The Wikipedia article lined in the first comment don't state that. (Yes, I know Wikipedia is not always correct. I'm just asking.)

Comment: @ispro: I was referring to PAKE schemes. Indeed that might be overblown here. Relevant (I hope) [PhD Thesis discussing SAS-based Message Authentication and Key Agreement Protocols](http://secu.famillepasini.ch/files/2009/phd/pasini_phd_thesis.pdf#page=83).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought device d1 can create a random number in the above mentioned range and use it as the key for Rijndael encryption of its public encryption key but without a need for padding so that all ciphertexts can be "decrypted" so that the MITM won't be able to brute force which is correct by being alerted that a wrong one is wrong.

Relying on the indistinguishability from random for a public key is a highly unusual security property and one that requires careful consideration of the schemes involved to not be violated.

Luckily, there's another alternative. Either you can use a balanced [PAKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) where one device generates the password and the user transmits it to the other - which is what the question tried to build. Or given that these "passwords" actually have no good reason to be picked beforehand we can use a Short-Authentication-String based key-exchange. [Sylvain Pasini's PhD thesis (PDF)](http://secu.famillepasini.ch/files/2009/phd/pasini_phd_thesis.pdf) is an excellent resource for that. In particular it offers a pre-instantiated authenticated key exchange in Figure 10.5:

- **Parameters:** A secure hash function $h$ like [SHA3-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) or [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), a [Diffie-Hellman group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) $\mathbb G$ with a generator $g$, e.g. [x25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) or secp256r1 or secp256k1, and a commitment scheme, e.g. [Pedersen Commitments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme#A_perfectly_binding_scheme_based_on_the_discrete_log_problem_and_beyond), a function $f$ that maps a 256-bit string to a human readable and verifiable (shortened?) representation while preserving as much entropy as possible, e.g. by interpreting the input as a 256-bit integer and performing a modular reduction $\bmod 10^{12}$.
- Alice picks a private DH key $x_A$ and computes $y_A\gets g^{x_A}$ - the DH public key. Alice then also picks a 256-bit uniformly random bit string $K$ and commits to both $y_A$ and $K$. Finally, Alice sends the commitment and the public key to Bob.
- Bob also picks a private DH key $x_B$ and computes $y_B\gets g^{x_B}$ and also picks a 256-bit string uniformly at random, called $R$. Bob transmits $y_B$ and $R$.
- Alice then sends the opening of the commitment to Bob. Alice displays the short authentication string (SAS) $f(R\oplus h(y_B,K))$.
- Bob now learns $K$ and confirms that the commitment was to $K$ and $y_A$, if it wasn't he aborts. Bob displays the SAS $f(R\oplus h(y_B,K))$.
- The user confirms that both displayed SAS strings match (on both devices). If a device doesn't receive a confirmation or if the user indicates different SAS to a device, it aborts.
- Alice outputs $y_B^{x_A}$ as the shared secret.
- Bob outputs $y_A^{x_B}$ as the shared secret.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like this does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [Socialist Millionaire Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaire_problem). A solution for it exists, as published in [this paper](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eberry/papers/dam.pdf).

According to Wikipedia:

> It is often used as a cryptographic protocol that allows two parties to verify the identity of the remote party through the use of a shared secret, avoiding a man-in-the-middle attack without the inconvenience of manually comparing public key fingerprints through an outside channel. In effect, a relatively weak password/passphrase in natural language can be used.

The protocol allows two parties to know whether or not they both share the same secret, such as a password, without transmitting it. If the other side, which may be an MITM attacker, is not able to prove that it has the same secret, then the session can be terminated before sending any sensitive information. Neither side learns any information about the secret in the process, other than the fact that the shared secrets did not match. If it succeeds and they do match, then they're MITM-free.

This technique is used in the [OTR protocol](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/Protocol-v3-4.1.1.html). Unauthenticated Diffie-Hellman key exchange is done first, after which SMP is performed within the encrypted channel. Further communication is denied unless the other side can prove that it shares the same secret and thus is not an MITM attacker. In order to successfully perform an MITM attack, the attacker would need to either correctly guess the shared secret in its entirety by performing multiple connection attempts and re-trying on each failure without alerting anyone to the attack, or solve the discrete logarithm problem (DLP) that underlies Diffie-Hellman security, which is currently thought to be hard when correct parameters are chosen.

A simplified explanation of the protocol and its properties as used in OTR is [available here](https://dustri.org/b/social-millionaires-protocol-in-otr.html).

Comment: Note that you'd probably want to use SMP to prove that the tuple (Transcript, Secret, Trusted Secret) matches (because if you do it on the DH resulting secret, a MITM attacker could just do it as well).

Comment: Thank you very much.